# Input/Output Error When Trying to Access Certain Directories

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am attempting to access a directory on an exfat formatted Seagate external hard drive, but I keep getting the error below. On my Mac computer, I am able to access directories and run scripts with no issues, but when using Ubuntu on my laptop, I started running into the error below. Up to today, I have had no problems accessing these directories on my laptop, but starting today, I get the following error when accessing certain directories:

```
ls: reading directory '/Volumes/EEG000/eeg/data/2015/book_17/00002026_20151021/patient/reports': Input/output error
```

This only happens with a select few directories, and I have not been able to figure out the cause. I have no problem accessing these directories on the Mac.

`dmesg` does not seem to report anything suspicious with the external hard drive either. Here are the last several lines:

```
[  456.419825] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 229)
[  456.419828] mce_notify_irq: 2 callbacks suppressed
[  456.419829] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[  456.419832] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 229)
[  456.419834] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[  456.439850] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[  456.439852] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439853] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439853] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[  456.439856] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439858] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439861] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439862] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439863] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[  456.439864] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
```

I have installed and reinstalled exFat-utils and exFat-fuse.

Also, here is the last several lines pertaining to the external hard drive in fdisk:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (4294967294 != 2743151278) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8001563221504 bytes, 15628053167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 23F0435C-410B-4B15-A778-FE0357B25EE2

Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      40      409639      409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  409640 15627790983 15627381344  7.3T Microsoft basic data
```

If you need more information, let me know and I will try to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by attempting to run `fsck` on the disk, which informed me that some of the files in the error prone directories had incorrect checksums. I fixed this by running Disk Utility to repair the corrupted files on the Mac computer.