# "ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error" only for 1 folder

Tags: command-line, transfer

I am using Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome 3.38.5.

Just 1 folder gives me:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

the rest of the Hard Disc works fine.
It happened while the external hard disc was moved during transfer and obviously the transfer stopped.
I am also getting a

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
```

when i run

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdc1
```

Also

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Gives me

```
e2fsck 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)
/dev/sdc1 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Now i can't see any files inside it and also, even though i was copying not moving, the files are nowhere.

I have checked those resources none seems to give me a solution:

[Error in brand new External Hard Drive: "ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017390/error-in-brand-new-external-hard-drive-ls-reading-directory-input-output)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445168/ls-reading-directory-input-output-error

[Error in brand new External Hard Drive: "ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017390/error-in-brand-new-external-hard-drive-ls-reading-directory-input-output)

[ls: reading directory ................': Input/output error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195640/ls-reading-directory-input-output-error)

[Input/Output Error When Trying to Access Certain Directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883409/input-output-error-when-trying-to-access-certain-directories)

Edit: added extra info

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; nor any messages that you read (or viewed in logs if you missed them). The messages are where I'd first look for clues (in logs if you didn't see them on the display).

Comment: ok thans @guiverc i have now added as much info as i could.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error trying to list ( ls ) a folder/directory on an External Hard Drive using Ubuntu 22.04 jammy:

```
'.': Input/output
```

I powered down the laptop during file transfer to the External Hard Drive folder/directory

Steps to solve:

- Connect External Hard drive to a computer with Windows 10 or Higher (I used windows 11)
- Go to My PC > select the external hard drive > right click and select properties> select Tools and run check ( chkdsk )
- The utility will scan and repair the external hard drive.
- This will result in a hidden protected folder/directory named found.000

To view the hidden folder/directory follow steps below:

1. Press  Windows Key.
2. Type File Explorer Options then Enter.
3. Select View Tab.
4. Uncheck Hide protected operating system files. (Recommended)
5. A prompt will appear, you will have to choose Yes or No if you want to continue changes made on your computer.
6. Then click Apply.

Reference available here: [Invisible found.000 folder after chkdsk](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/invisible-found000-folder-after-chkdsk/7d2ee59a-c495-4500-a369-a5ffa120fd21)

To access a found.000 folder that is locked/protected

1. Select the folder/directory and Go to folder properties
2. Security
3. Remove all permissions
4. Click Enable Inheritance
5. Click Apply

Reference available here: [How to access a found.000 folder that is locked](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-access-a-found000-folder-that-is-locked/9b3ae883-b868-4944-be3f-92d7cd30be19)

Now open found.000 folder/directory, there should be a folder named dir0000.chk with your folder/directory contents.